# Splitting lists and sublists in-place in dictionaries

Tags: python, loops, dictionary

I have a dictionary in the form

```
{country: [coordinate_set1,
           coordinate_set2,
           coordinate_set3]}
```

Where each coordinate_set is currently a long string of coordinate pairs thrown together.

How can I access each `coordinate_set` and split them into a list for every pair `x_coord;y_coord`

```
{country: [[set1_pair1][set1_pair2][set1_pair...],
           [set2_pair1][set2_pair2][set2_pair...],
           [set3_pair1][set3_pair2][set3_pair...]}
```

and then finally, inside these lists, make a tuple of every pair `x_coord, y_coord`

```
{country: [[x1_1,y1_1][x1_2,y1_2][x1_...,y1_],
           [x2_1,y2_1][x2_2,y2_2][x2_...,y2_],
           [x3_1,y3_1][x3_2,y3_2][x3_...,y3_]}
```

As these values are space-separated and semicolon-separated it should be fairly straightforward with `.split(" ")` and `.split(";")` on every string-element, but I can't figure out how to index and save splits.

I feel like it should be something along the lines of

```
for country, coordinate in dict.items():
    for coordinate_set in coordinate:
        split_set = coordinate_set.split(sep = " ")
        for xy_set in split_set:
            xy_tuple = tuple(xy_set.split(sep = ";")
```

But I can't really wrap my head around how to save these.

Sample data:
Edit: Updated with sample data

```
Antarctica
-80.0401787251;-59.5720946926 -80.5496566711;-59.865849372
-79.4970594217;-159.20818356 -79.634208673;-161.127601285
-78.0470696006;-45.1547576564 -78.4781027223;-43.9208278062
```

Comment: If you have sample data provide it

Comment: Edited. See now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do it, combination of list and dict comprehension:

```
{country: [tuple(xy_set.split(';')) for cordinate_set in coordinate for xy_set in cordinate_set.split()] for country, coordinate in dict.items()}
```

The `101` way:

```
result = {}
for country, coordinate in dict.items():
    for cordinate_set in coordinate:
        for xy_set in cordinate_set.split():
            e = tuple(xy_set.split(';'))
            if country in result:
                result[country].append(e)
            else:
                result[country] = [e]
```

Comment: Would you mind also doing it the Python 101 way, i.e. no comprehension?

Comment: I've added the `101` way :)

Comment: What is the meaning of "in in" and "for for" in this answer?

Comment: @BUFU spelling error, or something, happened long time ago :) Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Python 101 way

```
 dict1={'Antarctica':
    ['''-80.0401787251;-59.5720946926 -80.5496566711;-59.865849372
    -79.4970594217;-159.20818356 -79.634208673;-161.127601285
    -78.0470696006;-45.1547576564 -78.4781027223;-43.9208278062''']}
    for country, coordinate in dict1.items():
        cs=[]
        for coordinate_set in coordinate:
            split_set = coordinate_set.split(sep = " ")
            ss=[]
            for xy_set in split_set:
                xy_tuple = tuple(xy_set.split(sep = ";"))
                ss+=[xy_tuple]
            cs+=ss
        dict1[country]=cs

    print(dict1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Minor modifications without using comprehensions and less lines of code

```
data={'Antarctica':
    ["""-80.0401787251;-59.5720946926 -80.5496566711;-59.865849372 
    -79.4970594217;-159.20818356 -79.634208673;-161.127601285 
    -78.0470696006;-45.1547576564 -78.4781027223;-43.9208278062"""],'Ameriica':
    ["""-80.0401787251;-59.5720946926 -80.5496566711;-59.865849372 
    -79.4970594217;-159.20818356 -79.634208673;-161.127601285 
    -78.0470696006;-45.1547576564 -78.4781027223;-43.9208278062"""]}



for key,value in data.items():
      #print value
      updatevalue=[]
      inlist=value[0].split()

      for i in inlist:
            updatevalue.append(tuple(i.split(';')))
      data.update({key:updatevalue})

print data
```